# Не работает onClickListener во View

Tags: java, android, xml

Проблема заключается в том, что после смены разметки, перестал работать обработчик кликов.

Сам обработчик (В нем ничего не изменял, он как работал правильно, так и работает)

```
private View.OnClickListener getViewsClickListener(final int pos) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                Magazine m = magazines.get(pos);
                View view = views.get(pos);
                if(id == R.id.downloadPDF){
                    if(!m.isDownloadedPDF()) {
                        startDownload(m, view, true);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context,R.string.magazine_already_downloaded,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else if(id == R.id.downloadText){
                    if(!m.isDownloadedText()) {
                        startDownload(m, view, false);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context,R.string.magazine_already_downloaded,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else if(id == R.id.readPDF){
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EChangeFragment(new PDFFragment(), true, getPath(true, m)));
                }else if(id == R.id.readText){
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EChangeFragment(new TextFragment(), true, getPath(false, m)));
                }else if (id == R.id.cell){
                    switchShowMode(pos);
                }else if(id == R.id.preview){
                    switchShowMode(pos);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

**Разметка до**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cell"
        android:background="@color/cell_background"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img1"
            android:id="@+id/magazineImage"
            android:layout_width="95dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textColor="@color/floating_label"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/magazine_downloads"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/viewsCount"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|italic"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:id="@+id/titleSeparator"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/magazineImage"
            android:background="#ff000000" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/magazine_download_pdf"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/downloadText"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/preview"
            android:id="@+id/downloadPDF"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:elevation="2dp" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/magazine_download_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/downloadText"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/preview" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/magazine_read_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/readText"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/preview" />

        <Button
            android:text="@string/magazine_read_PDF"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/readPDF"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/downloadPDF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Разметка после**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:background="@color/contentBadgeTitle"
        android:elevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="115dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/downloadText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/magazine_download_text" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/readText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/magazine_read_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/downloadPDF"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/magazine_download_pdf" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/readPDF"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/magazine_read_PDF" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/magazineImage"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="115dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/titleSeparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/magazineImage"
                android:background="#ff000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/downloadsCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/downloadImage"
                android:text="@string/magazine_downloads"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/floating_label"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deleteMagazineImage"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleSeparator"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_magazine_cell_delete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/downloadImage"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_magazine_cell_downloads" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Заранее спасибо :3

По просьбе в комментах, публикую ещё часть кода, которая назначает слушатели

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.magazine_cell, parent, false);
            views.add(view);
        }

        Magazine magazine = getProduct(position);

        String viewsCount = String.valueOf(magazine.getViewsCount());
        String title = magazine.getTitle();
        String imageURL = magazine.getTitleImage();
        String preview = magazine.getPreview();
        viewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewTitle.setText(title);
        viewViewsCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadsCount);
        viewViewsCount.setText(viewsCount);
        viewPreview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.preview);
        viewPreview.setText(preview);
        viewPreview.setOnClickListener(getViewsClickListener(position));
        ImageView magazineImage =  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.magazineImage);
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL).into(magazineImage);
        cell = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cell);
        cell.setOnClickListener(getViewsClickListener(position));

        downloadPDF = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadPDF);
        downloadPDF.setOnClickListener(getViewsClickListener(position));
        downloadText = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadText);
        downloadText.setOnClickListener(getViewsClickListener(position));
        readText = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.readText);
        readText.setOnClickListener(getViewsClickListener(position));
        readPDF = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.readPDF);
        readPDF.setOnClickListener(getViewsClickListener(position));
        setPreviewMode(position);
        setButtonsColors(magazine, view);
        return view;
    }
```

Все это, как вы поняли, назначается в адаптере

@Sergey Gornostaev

> **UPD: Решение найдено**

Я просто переместил buttonsTable на уровень cell. Суть в том, что, видимо, т.к. buttonsTable находился внутри cell, листенер реагировал сначала на cell, и игнорировал кнопки

**КОД:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:background="@color/contentBadgeTitle"
        android:elevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/magazineImage"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/img1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="115dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/titleSeparator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/magazineImage"
                android:background="#ff000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/downloadsCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/downloadImage"
                android:text="@string/magazine_downloads"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/floating_label"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deleteMagazineImage"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleSeparator"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_magazine_cell_delete" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/downloadImage"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_magazine_cell_downloads" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="115dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/downloadText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:text="@string/magazine_download_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/readText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text="@string/magazine_read_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/downloadPDF"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:text="@string/magazine_download_pdf" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/readPDF"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:text="@string/magazine_read_PDF" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Куда интереснее было бы увидеть код, который обработчик назначает.

Comment: Кучу `if-else` целесообразно заменить на `switch-case`.

Comment: Если вынести кнопки в (RelativeLayout) cell, то слушатели работают нормально